# Can Private session along with Inproc be used if the XDB and analytics are not in use

Tags: session-state

In our application, we are using the session variable just to get the information between pages.Example cart quantity

We have load balancer setup for 2 CD serves with stick session

We are not using any XDB concepts.

In this scenario, can we use the private session along with InProc mode.

Is there any better way to achieve the mentioned requiremnt.

Answer (score 2):

Say someone starts a session using their desktop PC and the load balancer sticks this session to CD server #1.
Now this same person also starts a session with their mobile phone, but this the time load balancer sticks the session to CD server #2.

This causes potential issues!
If data in the Contact object is changed or engagement plan states are changed in both sessions, then one session will override the other.
This is at least true in pre 9.0 xDB scenarios, it's may be different when using  xConnect (post 9.0)

Only if this scenario is very unlikely in your case, you could choose to go with InProc, but it's better in general to not use sticky sessions on your load balancer and just use the OutProc session provider.
Seeing as you are using only 2 CD servers, it's probably safe to just use the same SQL Server for your session state database as you use for your Sitecore content databases, so there is really no reason to not use OutProc sessions.

Comment: Thanks Ruud. We had planned to use the existing sql server session db. i.e private with sql

Answer (score 1):

I have inherited a project years ago with a similar setup (sticky load balancer, InProc sessions, no xdb - that didn't even exist in that version). This project had evolved in such a way that switching to OutProc sessions was no longer an option without a rather large refactoring. And the site has been running fine for all those years.

So, yes - you can.

But to be honest, if I (could) rewrite this project the sessions will be OutProc. It gives you more flexibility - e.g. no need for sticky sessions - now or in the future.

Comment: Thanks.We had planned to use the existing sql server session db. i.e private with sql